# Best practice for provided implementations of interfaces

Tags: java, oop, interface

I'm developing a library in Java which contains some functionality where some values will have to be run through some function in order to transform or map them in a way.  If you want more detail, it's a robotics library where sets of motor output levels will need to be mathematically changed.

Currently, the way I've implemented this is through a `Mapper` interface with a `run` method which the map method accepts. Users use it like this:

```
wheelValues.map(new Mapper() {
    @Override
    public double run(double input) { ••• }
});
```

The thing is, I want to include some default implementations of the Mapper interface for user convenience, for example, an absolute value Mapper. I want to make it a property of the Mapper interface some how. What is the best way to approach this, a static inner class or static public fields?

```
public interface Mapper {
    // This?
    static final Mapper ABS = new Mapper() {...}
    // Or this?
    static class Abs implements Mapper {...}
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. I would recommend a static method that returns a new instance of your default implementation. That way, multiple callers will each get their own instance. I would also consider renaming your `run()` method to something else, for example `transform()`. This better indicates what the method does (run infers a thread being executed).

Comment: @Jason You very rarely want each caller to have their own instance.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I'd say that depends on the implementation of the solution. Given the information above, there's no way to tell if each caller should get their own instance or one shared instance. Using a static method, the implementation of the method can decide which way to go. A static field restricts that decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by using standard library interfaces wherever possible; for example, your `Mapper` seems like a duplicate of `DoubleFunction` (or `Function<Double, Double>`). Absolute value is provided by `Math.abs`, and you can already refer to it saying `Math::abs`, no "default implementation" required.

Regarding the question of out-of-the-box implementations, there are two general categories:

- Completely pure functions (that have no knobs or settings) are generally implemented as constants somewhere. A good example of this is [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER), which is a constant of `Comparator<String>` that does what its name says.
- Functions that need a private copy because they have some sort of parameter are implemented as static methods that return an instance of that functional interface. A good example here is `Predicate.isEqual(target)`, which returns a `Predicate` (object->boolean) instance which returns true if the value examined is equal to the target value (provided when the instance is created): `private static final Predicate IS_CORRECT = Predicate.isEqual(correctAnswer)`.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. Sadly, I am not able to use functional interfaces as this code must be able to run in an older (Marshmallow) Android environment which does not support JDK 8 features. However, your advice on out-of-the-box implementations is greatly appreciated.

Comment: While your answer may be technically correct, there are cases where it is preferable to use a custom interface as it often provides additional contextual information to future maintainers / users of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Make the API as small a reasonably practical. So don't add a extra class where a static method or final field will suffice.

An `enum` would make a bad choice. As, for example, [`java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html).

OTOH, you can't allow varying type parameters if you use enum constants or static fields, so a method may be preferable, if only for consistency. As, for example, [`java.util.Collections.emptySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet()) or [`java.util.stream.collectors.toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()).

In order not to create too many instances you may want a private static field behind any method.

Avoid the naming classes `Default`, or other poorly descriptive names. Even if it is the class returned by a default method.